# How to implement deferred rendering for datatable in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I have used datatable for my project. I have downloaded it from Github. Its working fine but showing problem now as my data has increases. For this i want to implement defered rending concept like done in JQuery

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

Below in Github link

https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? Use `withOption('deferRender', true)` ...

Comment: Can you please provide the full syntax?

Comment: hey @pkk, this is the full syntax using `DTOptionsBuilder` ...

Comment: I use this DTOptionsBuilder.withOption('deferRender', true); getting error withOption is not a function.

Comment: I want this option in angular1 way not in JQuery or in Angular2

Comment: Try read up on how to use angular datatables. I am not a librarian, but here goes -> **http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withOptions**

Comment: They have updated the files for Angular2 that's why facing problem to get that option.

Comment: Follow the link I posted above.